# How to return a boolean value from async callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if a user is in a specific group.
But I need to know the bool value in the calling function.

I have debugged the code below and its OK, but as I dont know very well the js syntax I need some help.

All I need is to have isCurrentUserInGroup true or false so I can make further comparissons.

```
var isCurrentUserInGroup= IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Approvers");



    function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            return userInGroup;
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            return false;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Use a promise: http://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: thanks, but prefer to know how to do it without external libraries.

Comment: The site goes into how to write your own implementation, it's not just a library... Use the concepts within to write your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a callback to your "IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup" function.

```
IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Approvers", function(isSuccess){
    // do what you want with "isSuccess"
});

function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, callback) {

    var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

    var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    currentContext.load(currentUser);

    var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);

    var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
    currentContext.load(group);

    var groupUsers = group.get_users();
    currentContext.load(groupUsers);

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

    function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
        var userInGroup = false;
        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                userInGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }  
        callback(userInGroup);
    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        callback(false);
    }    
}
```